# Choppy audio playback with AudioTrack.write

Tags: android, pcm, audiotrack

I am using AudioTrack library to play pcm samples that are being streamed via wifi. The problem is the playback is very choppy while playing on **Lenovo K900 (4.1.2)**, whereas it is seamless while playing on **OnePlusOne (Marshmallow 6.0.1 cyanogen)** handset. 
To rule out streaming delay I first loaded the entire stream in an array then played the audio by looping over the pre-populated array. Still things do not improve at all. 
Now **K900** is running **Android 4.1.2** whereas the android sdk I used is for **API23**, I mean when I open the definition of AudioTrack class it open the class file of **API23**. Is it causing any problem?

```
               int bufferSize = AudioTrack.getMinBufferSize(SAMPLE_RATE, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_MONO,
                        AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_8BIT);
                if (bufferSize == AudioTrack.ERROR || bufferSize == AudioTrack.ERROR_BAD_VALUE) {
                    bufferSize = SAMPLE_RATE * 2;
                }
                int readBytes;
                int bufSize=2123880;//size of the file being streamed
                byte[] buffer=new byte[bufSize];
                //bufferSize*=2;
                DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
                readBytes=0;
                while(true) {
                    try {
                        if(in.available()>0){
                            readBytes+=in.read(buffer, readBytes, in.available());
                        //    audioTrack.write(buffer,0,readBytes);
                        }else{
                            break;
                        }
                    } catch (SocketTimeoutException s) {
                        System.out.println("Socket timed out!");
                        //audioTrack.release();
                        break;
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        //audioTrack.release();
                        break;
                    }
                }
                in.close();
                readBytes=0;
                AudioTrack audioTrack = new AudioTrack(
                        AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,
                        SAMPLE_RATE,
                        AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_MONO,
                        AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_8BIT,
                        bufferSize,
                        AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM);
                audioTrack.play();
                while(readBytes<bufSize){
                    readBytes+=audioTrack.write(buffer,readBytes,bufferSize);
                }
                audioTrack.release();
```

I tested with samples having different sampling rate ranging from **19250hz** to **44100hz**. For all cases **K900** strong text is playing choppy whereas Oneplus one plays smooth. I dont think that **K900** is underpowered to pull up this easy job.
Kindly assist.

**EDIT**
Here is the code I intend to use:

```
              try {
                //dataInputStream = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
                //response = dataInputStream.readUTF();
                int bufferSize = AudioTrack.getMinBufferSize(SAMPLE_RATE, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_MONO,
                        AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_8BIT);

                if (bufferSize == AudioTrack.ERROR || bufferSize == AudioTrack.ERROR_BAD_VALUE) {
                    bufferSize = SAMPLE_RATE * 2;
                }

                int readBytes;
                byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
                bufferSize = bufferSize * 2;
                AudioTrack audioTrack = new AudioTrack(
                        AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,
                        SAMPLE_RATE,
                        AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_STEREO,
                        AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_8BIT,
                        bufferSize,
                        AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM);
                audioTrack.play();
                DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
                while (true) {
                    try {
                        if (in.available() > 0) {
                            readBytes = in.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length);
                            audioTrack.write(buffer, 0, readBytes);
                        }
                    } catch (SocketTimeoutException s) {
                        System.out.println("Socket timed out!");
                        audioTrack.release();
                        in.close();
                        socket.close();
                        break;
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        audioTrack.release();
                        in.close();
                        socket.close();
                        break;
                    }
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

Thanks,
Debojit

Comment: you have `int bufferSize = AudioTrack.getMinBufferSize(...` so what do you need `int bufSize=2123880;` for?

Comment: Well I just cached the entire stream content in the buffer by reading the data input stream and then played from that buffer itself to rule out any streaming delay.

Comment: so do not use `AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM`, use `MODE_STATIC` instead

Comment: Using static is not my objective, i want to play via stream, as it is not playing properly i used this approach to check if this plays well as it would be reading from array instead of stream. Please check the code in the edit part.

Comment: then try [this](http://pastebin.com/raw/tz2Mvh5G)

Comment: Ok, so you are asking me to try with a wav sample. Well I will create a sample of 44100hz with audacity and try playing that. I will let you know the output.

Comment: I could not get much time to try out this, but fortunately I am able to play and record simultaneously on oneplusone. I mean recording on the phone and sending to other end of socket, and receiving a sample from the other end of the socket

Comment: what does it have to do with choppy audio?

Comment: Actually my original project is to have full duplex audio transmission over wifi. Now I was stuck with a specific device (K900). I just got rid of that problem using another device (oneplusone). I ran the same program on nexus 4, that also works perfectly (i.e., works on oneplusone+nexus 4, but does not work on K900). So i thought to have the original problem solved, and then work on any device specific issue.